# How to call a non static public method from a Singleton class which is using Google @Inject

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, guice

I have a Singleton class that I want to test. It uses a @Inject annotation for that class's contructor. Now for testing I want to call a public method for that class in my test class but unable to do so. I have mocked an object that is getting passed to the constructor.

```
@Inject
    private SomeClass(SomeOtherClassObject obj) {
        super(obj);
    }
```

I mocked the above private constructor in the following way:

```
Singleton mockSingleton = PowerMock.createMock(Singleton.class);
        PowerMock.expectNew(Singleton.class).andReturn(mockSingleton);
```

I dont understand how do I call the following method

```
public SomeClass someMethod(int 1, String 2){

//some logic

return (Object of SomeClass)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Making the constructor private is the best way to make your class untestable. Make it at least package-protected, so that the test can call the constructor.

Comment: I understand that but I cant chjange the class code. I just need to test it. Any suggestions? Also, I just noticed I get an error when I try to run a test and error it gives for is that the constructor is not what it is expected. How do I pass the mock object that I have to the constructor which I have created using the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using guice as well, you can provide a module in your test that binds SomeOtherClassObject to your mock instance. Then create the SomeClass instance via Guice's injector.

```
@Test
public void test() {
  SomeOtherClassObject other = ...; // what ever you need to create the Mock
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule(){
    public void configure() {
      bind(SomeOtherClassObject.class)toInstance(other);
    }
   });
   SomeClass some = injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class); // guice takes care of the constructor injection
   some.someMethod(...);
  }
```

If you dont use guice, have a look at [needle4j](http://needle4j.org/). Its a test-support lib that automatically injects mocks when injection is required. But it works only with easymock or mockito.